# Paypal Custom Shipping Rates In The Sdk

Tags: paypal

I'm new to the Paypal SDK.  I've managed to pass the cart total from Laravel 8 cart in the Paypal code, but I'm looking to add shipping rates based on different types of shipping, like economy and priority mail, but I want to do it for different states.  Does anybody know some sdk code to do this, and the code to add that to the cart total?  Here is what I've done so far...

```
paypal.Buttons({
          createOrder: function(data, actions) {
              return actions.order.create({
                  purchase_units: [{
                      amount: {
                          value: "{{ $cartTotal }}",
                          currency_code: "USD"
                      },
                      shipping: {
                          options: [
                              {
                                  id: "SHIP_123",
                                  label: "Free Shipping",
                                  type: "SHIPPING",
                                  selected: true,
                                  amount: {
                                      value: "3.00",
                                      currency_code: "USD"
                                  }
                              },
                              {
                                  id: "SHIP_456",
                                  label: "Pick up in Store",
                                  type: "PICKUP",
                                  selected: false,
                                  amount: {
                                      value: "0.00",
                                      currency_code: "USD"
                                  }
                              }
                          ]
                      }
                  }]
              });
          },

        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
            // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
            alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
          });
        }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container');
      //This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
```

Answer (score 0):

> but I want to do it for different states

To calculate an amount for different addresses, you need to use an `onShippingChange` callback function for once the buyer has selected an address.

It appears you already found the sample code on [Support multiple shipping options](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/configure-payments/shipping-options/), so read further down that page.

Reference `data.shipping_address` to determine the selected country and state, and return actions.order.patch to make any changes to the order , or actions.reject if there is no shipping to that location. See further sample code in [the SDK reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/javascript-sdk/javascript-sdk-reference/#onshippingchange).

Comment: When I do the onShippingChange by itself, the cart total doesn't change.  I have to add the shipping values together with the cartotal for it to change, but I shouldn't have to do that.  Is there a way for some sample code for shipping rates, especially shipping rates for different cart  total prices to go with different locations. Don't know why paypal makes so hard.  Is there sample code or a clear cut example that I can mimic and pickup?  Thanks

Comment: I didn't have room to mention, that how exactly do you reference data.shipping_address without breaking the code.  I don't know why Paypal doesn't have a code builder for their sdk script.

Comment: The linked documents have sample code. You reference a variable by using it, for example ` if (data.shipping_address.country_code !== 'US')` in that sample code is a straightforward and simple check. Do other things if you want to do other things.  To change the order, use actions.order.patch

Comment: Will try your suggestions.  Is it possible to implement from and to values in this code to reflect different cart total prices for the shipping?  Haven't found and documentation on that.  Thanks again for the help.